# Visa with criminal record

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, criminal-records

I am from India and I have recently travelled to Germany. I had a visa type C that allowed to stay there for 9 days. I entered Germany on 6th March, 2017 and I was supposed to leave Germany on 14th March, 2017. But I had to leave on 16th March, 2017.

Unfortunately, while coming back to India, my flight from Berlin to Frankfurt was cancelled due to an airport strike in Berlin. The airline was Lufthansa. My flight from Berlin to Frankfurt was supposed to leave Berlin at 07:45  and reach Frankfurt at 08:55. My connecting flight to Chennai leaves Frankfurt at 10:15. I reached Berlin airport at 06:30 only to find out that my flight had gotten cancelled. They had not even informed me about the strike until I went to their counter in Berlin airport.

Had I been informed of the strike earlier, I would have directly gone to Frankfurt to catch my flight to Chennai. They said there wasn't any flight available for 2 days (i.e free) out of Germany to India and they couln't accommodate me in Frankfurt. So, I asked them to book for the next available flight, which was after 2 days. After 2 days, on reaching Frankfurt airport from Berlin, I was stopped at Immigration, saying that I had stayed in Germany longer than what my visa permitted.

I was then escorted to the police station where the police charged me with a criminal offence legal code 95 Abs. 1 Nr. 2 AufenthG. I boarded the next flight back to India and came back. Here, I would like to know 4 things:

1. Will my passport be blacklisted or something forever?
2. Will this criminal record show up every time my passport is checked/swiped by any country's immigration department?
3. How should I proceed while applying for visas to other countries. Ex: the Hong Kong pre-arrival registration form has a question that asks a person if they had ever over-stayed/have any criminal record in other countries. So, how should I answer this?
4. I am planning to do my Master's abroad. Will the universities be aware of the incident using my passport number?

Comment: 1. Not forever but yes it will be blacklisted or flagged. 2. Not every country, Schengen and a few others 3. You should answer the truth which is that you have overstayed however not a criminal record. Do you mean you did not have proof to show them your earlier flight was cancelled which is why you overstayed?

Comment: I have the proof. But, they just wouldn't listen(German immigration officers)

Comment: Apply for another Schengen and have all the evidence with you. Once you are granted a new Schengen, it will clear you a bit. Also next time you're entering the Schengen zone, carry the proof with you. Finally it's not a good idea to be leaving on the last day your visa expires. Things happen and it's good to give yourself a few days margin. Germans are notoriously strict with immigration.

Comment: OP's story doesn't add up. I'm sure there is more to it.

Comment: My biggest doubt is that I am student from India, I am planning to do my Masters abroad. Can the universities know of my situation just by my passport number/ passport?

Comment: @greatone What do you think doesn't add up. That's what happened. I am a 21 year old who visited Germany who had to stay back because my flight had gotten cancelled due to Berlin airport strike on 14th March 2017. I called Lufthansa if there was any flight out to India and they said there weren't any that were available. On being stopped at Frankfurt's immigration, I showed them my initial flight tickets too.

Comment: The German authorities should have extended your visa.  The Schengen Visa Code says, at Article 33 (1), *The period of validity and/or the duration of stay of an issued visa shall be extended where the competent authority of a Member State considers that a visa holder has provided proof of force majeure or humanitarian reasons preventing him from leaving the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the period of validity of or the duration of stay authorised by the visa. Such an extension shall be granted free of charge.*

Comment: @GayotFow Please check the updated question. My airlines said that there was no available flight out of Frankfurt to India for 2 days and they couldn't give me accommodation in Frankfurt.

Comment: Note that 95 Abs. 1 Nr. 2 AufenthG is about criminal penalties. Apparently the OP has been *informed by the police* that he was accused of a crime. It seems he has not been charged by a prosecutor or sentenced by a court. It might be useful to keep that difference in mind for future applications, anywhere in the world.

Comment: @GayotFow Do you mean if Lufthansa has asked me what DB said about the whole situation? Why would DB say anything? Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you please elucidate a little more.

Comment: @GayotFow   I didn't take the train because I didn't want to get stranded in Frankfurt. They said that all the flights from Frankfurt to India were completely booked for 2 days. So, how should I proceed the next time I apply for Schengen visa?

Comment: @RaviKuntineni I guess what gayot means is that if there was a strike in Berlin, why couldn't you get to Frankfurt by train(apparently it is only 4 hours), in time to catch your connection to India?

Comment: @RedBaron Thank you. I have included the timings in the question. Please check.

Comment: Something that does not add up is that there were no other flights they could redirect you for two days. If you got an offer to be redirected that was just "too much of a hassle" for you, then it is actually your fault that you overstayed. If the flight was canceled, they would have been legally obliged to provide you with accommodation until you can reach your redirected flight.

Comment: @skymningen I was told by Lufthansa staff that there were no flights available for 2 days and they couldn't give me any accommodation. I didn't know that they were legally obliged to provide me with accommodation. But, are they really legally obliged?

Comment: http://www.lufthansa.com/cmn/en/passenger-rights As far as I know, accommodation is part of "re-routing, care, refund and compensation", more specifically "care". Although they seem to not be obliged if it is a strike, which might have been the problem. But I know of people who got accommodation for flights canceled because of bad weather.

Answer (score 9):

A criminal record is not an issue *per se*. There is no question asking to disclose it on the Schengen visa application form and no systematic exchange of criminal records between Schengen countries. Some other countries do ask you to disclose that or any previous visa refusal or removal and are stricter with this. The specifics would depend on the country in question but it seems you have at least been removed and that's often relevant.

A ban on the other hand would obviously prevent you from entering the Schengen area (that's the point). You can be banned for an immigration violation without being found guilty of a crime, this is not really linked to criminal records one way or the other. I believe there are some efforts underway to harmonise this further but member states have a lot of leeway in deciding whether to impose a ban or not. In some countries, even a longer overstay that gets your visa cancelled and/or detention and a police escort to your plane does not always results in a ban.

Based on the facts disclosed in your question, I agree with @phoog that your visa could and should have been extended but the German authorities are notorious for issuing bans very aggressively compared to other countries. If you have indeed been banned, applying for a Schengen visa is pointless, you first need to get the ban lifted to avoid an automatic refusal and only the country that issued the ban can lift it.

Whatever the case may be, you would certainly not be blacklisted forever for a mere overstay. An entry in the Schengen Information System last for three years by default but member states can renew it as they see fit. IIRC, a German ban is typically 10 years.

More generally, there is no global database of passports, criminal records or immigration history. Specific countries do have limited form of information exchange, often for intelligence purposes and not so much for regular immigration purposes. There are also databases of stolen documents and wanted persons (both at the EU level and through Interpol) but that does not seem relevant here.

The main concern is that you will often be asked to disclose this event and lying about it exposes you to many unpleasant consequences. Even without a database, there are many ways to be found out (stamps in a passport, contradicting yourself in an interview, being tipped off by an ex-boyfriend or jealous neighbour, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have not been banned or blacklisted. The case is still pending. Hopefully I might be let off with just a fine because I had no malicious intent on staying. The thing is, I am not at all familiar with foreign immigration policies. I don't know how to approach this situation. I have been given a receipt by the German police that consists of the case that they have booked against me and also the contact number of a lawyer who represents me. How should I contact them. How can I know the status of my case?

Comment: @RaviKuntineni Did you contact the lawyer in question? Getting help from a professional seems necessary in this situation.

Comment: No, I haven't contacted him. I will contact him now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just regarding your 1st and 4th question, it isn't the **passport** which gets listed in the SIS, it is the **person**. They collected biometric data from you and getting a new passport won't help.

Comment: How do I answer the following questions? They are in Hong Kong pre-arrival registration. They are of the type Yes/No.

Comment: "Have you ever committed or been arrested for any overstaying, illegal immigration or other criminal offence in the HKSAR or any country/territory?"

Comment: "If yes, have you ever been convicted of the offence(s)?"

Comment: @RaviKuntineni, I can't say for certain. If you had been arrested or convicted, you would have some sort of paperwork. I don't know how Hong Kong law defines committed.

Comment: Thank you. But,  I am not convicted or arrested. I have just been accused of illegal stay and have been given a receipt of the charge they filed against me.

Comment: And, could you please explain me a bit more about the sections I have been charged with. 95 Abs. 1 Nr. 2 AufenthG ?

Comment: Actually the SIS does not necessarily contain biometrics. There are provision to include some in the SIS-II but I don't think it's the case for most entries so far. In most cases it's the name and date of birth that will be used to identify a person and you don't need biometrics to catch someone who merely renewed their passport. And even the biometrics have been collected (as they are for the VIS for example), it's often for the purpose of double-checking someone's identity, not for database-wide search (only Eurodac works that way AFAIK).

Comment: Incidentally, I assume your first sentence refers to alerts for the purpose of refusing entry and stay, which do indeed pertain to a person, but in fact most of the entries are about passports (namely lost or stolen documents).

Comment: @RaviKuntineni, I'm not a lawyer and not qualified to give legal advice. The law on visa, residency permits etc. contains a section defining criminal offenses. Staying in Germany without valid permit is a misdemeanor and can be punished with prison up to one year or a fine. *(This is not as bad as it sounds. For a first offense the sentence would be* much *lower than the maximum, and it would almost certainly be followed by a conditional discharge.)* The consequences for getting another visa will be much more bothersome than the misdemeanor.

Comment: @o.m the immigration officers or police don't have the authority yo convict someone of a crime. Only a judge can do that. He maybe charged but not convicted. Anyhow, the whole incident is beyond ridiculous. Surely, the Germans can't be that unreasonable.

Comment: @greatone. Thank you. Even I find it ridiculous that they stopped me for 2 days overstay for what I think is due to a valid reason.

Comment: @greatone, I explained that difference in my comment to the question. And I don't find it "ridiculous" -- if it were OK to overstay two days, the next guy will argue that two weeks are OK, or two months.

Comment: @o.m a criminal charge for something out of the OP's hands?

Comment: @greatone, see the comments for the original question -- it should not take two days to get from Berlin to Frankfurt, even if the flight is cancelled. I agree that the OP should not be convicted, or possibly not even charged, but that is not for the police to decide. I'm also not clear if the OP tried to get a visa extension on March **16th**, i.e. before his visa expired, or only afterwards.

Comment: @o.m. Thank you so much, your answer. I actually didn't know that there was a facility for visa extension. Had I known about that, I would have gotten it the day my flight had gotten cancelled. That was my first trip abroad. Going to Frankfurt wasn't going to reduce the overstay. Then I would be staying for 2 days in Frankfurt than in Berlin. I am not yet convicted or anything. I have just been charged. I am just worried if this incident will hinder my chances of getting visa every time further.